# MySQL - complicated LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have that one-to-many relationship going here.  Plus, not all "primary" records will have a joined record in the second database table.

Here are my tables:

tbl_customers
tbl_addresses

A customer record in `tbl_customers` can obviously have many addresses, in the `tbl_addresses` table.

Here's my dilemma.  There are many customer records with several addresses, and I assign one of those address records as the "main" address for a customer record.  This is simply a single `column` called: `primaryAddress`.  The value will be a number 1, if that address record is the main address.

So here is my query:

```
SELECT c.customername, a.state 
FROM `tbl_customers` c
LEFT JOIN `tbl_addresses` a ON c.customerid = a.customerid
```

That query will result in duplicate records for any customer with more than 1 address.
If I add a little more to the LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT c.customername, a.state 
FROM `tbl_customers` c
LEFT JOIN `tbl_addresses` a ON c.customerid = a.customerid AND a.primaryAddress = 1
```

This produces no results, even when I see in the database there are plenty of address records with primaryAddress = 1.

So I'm thinking my query is wrong.

Can someone see what I'm missing?

Comment: I should add that there are many customer records without an address record yet.  I still need to display those customers, but leave the a.state as empty.  (which is why I chose LEFT JOIN).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your second query as written. Is there anything else you've left out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who happens to land on this page looking for a solution:

> **THIS DOES NOT PROPERLY ANSWER THE QUESTION**

The user was able to find the cause after discussing the problem here. Turns out he had a typo on his original code. **The second block of SQL code posted on the question is correct, and should give the expected results**. +1 for user JoeStefanelli for pointing this out.

Please read the comments for details. My original answer is below. Now I see I should have deleted it, instead of trying to amend it, as soon I realized it was flawed. At least the discussion helped the user find a solution...

---

My original answer:

> You are almost there. Add `a.primaryAddress = 1` to the `WHERE` clause instead.
>
> **EDIT**
>
> Not sure if this will exclude costumers with zero addresses from the results...

Comment: No. Adding that condition to the WHERE clause will force the JOIN to behave like an INNER JOIN. It is correct where it is.

Comment: You're right.  It excludes the customers with no addresses.  darn it

Comment: Yeah, that's what I though realized after answering. But I can't see why the second query on your question produces no results! I'm testing with a similar structure, and it works for me.

Comment: You're right!  I mistyped the alias in my query box, if you can believe that.  I love wasting time!!  Thanks!

Comment: -1 Even though this answer was accepted, it is incorrect and could be misleading for anyone who reads this question in the future.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I know you can't delete the answer since it's been accepted, but I'd encourage you to edit it and put some kind of disclaimer at the top.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I've removed my down vote. Your edit should make everything clear to future readers.